# Xcode 6.4 - Navigation Bar not editable

Tags: xcode, storyboard, uinavigationbar

Just to prove I'm not going mad here's my app working, complete with a Nav Bar.

[image]

But this is what it looks like in the Main.storyboard, no Nav Bar.

[image]

I have rectified this is the past by disconnecting the link from the TabBar controller and restablishing it. I want to be able to edit Nav Bar as I seem to have two back buttons. One comes up and < and the other as < Back, shown top.

What's the fix and have I created the View in the wrong order?

Many thanks.

Comment: If you click on the View Controller and then to go Edit -> Embed In -> Navigation Controller, you'll get the navigation bar back, presumably.

Comment: Will try in try in the morning - many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an image of where to go if you need a navigation bar in a View Controller.

[image]

If you need to add Bar Buttons, you can use a `Navigation Item` as well.

Comment: No joy. The still the Title/Back button are nowhere in sight, in either Controller. In previous versions of Xcode you could see the entities in a view, such as the number of Nav bar items on the left. I suspect I've added an extra Back Button but can' see how to edit it. If I have to recreate the View want to make sure I do it correctly this time.

Comment: The Attributes Inspector with Title/Back Button is not showing, does that help?

Comment: I have removed all the links to the view and established them and the Title Bar has reappeared. I can now edit the title/back button, but why?

Comment: It could be one of your segues to that view is not a `show` but something else, maybe a modal. If it is, that would mean no navigation bar would appear.

Comment: No it's not that but it is probably something like that - many thanks.

Comment: Did you figure out the right answer? In the comments, it seems to point you in the right direction but there is no conclusion. I'm having this same issue and would appreciate it if you can post your findings. Thanks.